# What am I doing wrong blackjack file counter in Java?

Tags: java, counter, blackjack

I am doing this exercise, the exercise says this:

*Given an input file containing 1000 random blackjack hands between 3 players (here: blackjack.txt), calculate the number of blackjacks encountered for any player in all games.

A blackjack is defined as an Ace of any suit and a 10 valued card (Jack, Queen ,King or 10) of any suit.

The input file looks like this: (as an example)

4H 5C AD JH 9C 10H

This means that player one has a 4 of hearts and a 5 of clubs; player 2 has an Ace of Diamonds and a Jack of Hearts (which counts as a blackjack); player 3 has a 9 of Clubs and a 10 of Hearts.

For the purpose of this problem, it is known that there is a standard 52 card deck which is reshuffled for each new game.*

I think I am in the correct approach, and my code is correct, but my answers fails, any hint, suggestion for getting a right answer

this is my code:

```
import java.io.*;

public class Problema16 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        File archivo = null;
        FileReader fr = null;
        BufferedReader br = null;
        int counter = 0;
        //int rest = 0;

        try {
            archivo = new File("C:\\Users\\\blackjack.txt");
            fr = new FileReader(archivo);
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String linea;
            String[] linea2 = null;

            while ((linea = br.readLine()) != null) //System.out.println(linea);
            {
                linea2 = linea.split(" ");

                String a = (linea2[0]);
                String b = (linea2[1]);
                String c = (linea2[2]);
                String d = (linea2[3]);
                String e = (linea2[4]);
                String f = (linea2[5]);

                if ((a.startsWith("A") && (b.startsWith("J") || (b.startsWith("Q") || (b.startsWith("K") || (b.startsWith("10")))))) || ((a.startsWith("J") || (a.startsWith("Q") || (a.startsWith("K") || (a.startsWith("10"))))) && (b.startsWith("A")))) {
                    counter++;
                    //System.out.println(a + "" + b + "");
                } else if ((c.startsWith("A") && (d.startsWith("J") || (d.startsWith("Q") || (d.startsWith("K") || (d.startsWith("10")))))) || ((c.startsWith("J") || (c.startsWith("Q") || (c.startsWith("K") || (c.startsWith("10"))))) && (d.startsWith("A")))) {
                    counter++;
                    //System.out.println(c + "" + d + "");
                } else if ((e.startsWith("A") && (f.startsWith("J") || (f.startsWith("Q") || (f.startsWith("K") || (f.startsWith("10")))))) || ((e.startsWith("J") || (e.startsWith("Q") || (e.startsWith("K") || (e.startsWith("10"))))) && (f.startsWith("A")))) {
                    counter++;
                    //System.out.println(e + "" + f + "");
                } else {
                    //sobra++;
                }
            }

            System.out.println(counter);
            //System.out.println(sobra);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

this is the exercise online [1](http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=16). My answers is 119, but is wrong.

Comment: Please define what you mean by "my answer fails".  What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I am no getting an error in the code , just the answers I obtain fails

Comment: Fails how?  What result are you getting?  What result were you expecting?

Comment: I get 119, but when I enter to http://www.cstutoringcenter.com/problems/problems.php?id=16 It says that my answers is wrong

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your conditions in each `if` are hard to read with all the braces but seem OK.
Your problem lies in `else if`. Player #1 and Player #2 (and Player #3) can have blackjack **at the same time** where as your code will only count 1 of them.

Drop the `else` and you should be OK.

You can also improve the readability of your code a little. Some pointers:

- Checking 2nd / 3rd players' hands involves the same logic as first. Use a loop.
- Instead of explicitly checking for specific cards perhaps you can calculate the value of the hand and check if it equals 21. It'd be nice to put that logic in a separate method.
- A simple way to calculate hand's value (assuming input is always legal) is to drop the suit (since it's irrelevant) and use a predefined map to determine card value (e.g. "J" => 10, "A" - 11, etc.)

Comment: thanks a lot, my answers now is 123, I delete else and Its ok

Answer (score 1):

A short sed-command to verify:

```
sed 's/[CDHS] / /g;s/[CDHS]\r$//g;s/[JKQ]/+/g;s/10/+/g;s/A/-/g;s/\(. .\)/[\1]/g;s/+ -/ * /g;s/- +/ * /g' blackjack.txt | grep " \* " | wc -l 
119 lines
```

delete colors, combine JKQ10 to +, A to - (a bit superflous), +- and -+ to * (BJ).

Multimatches:

```
sed 's/[CDHS] / /g;s/[CDHS]\r$//g;s/[JKQ]/+/g;s/10/+/g;s/A/-/g;s/\(. .\)/[\1]/g;s/+ -/ * /g;s/- +/ * /g' blackjack.txt | grep " \*.*\* " 
[6 5] [ * ] [ * ]
[3 +] [ * ] [ * ]
[ * ] [ * ] [4 4]
[5 8] [ * ] [ * ]
```

4x 2hits. 119+4 = 123

Patternmatching could of course be used to produce a java solution in a similar way.

Comment: can you explain this, I dont understand what are you doing?

Comment: Do you know sed? It's a stream editor, which is mostly used to do pattern matching and replacing with very short commands. I modify all input strings like '4H 5C AD JH 9C 10H'. We don't care about the colors (HCDHCH), so we can remove them. We don't need to differenciate between 10, J, Q, K. So I transform JQK10 to +, and +A and A+ to *, to mark all Blackjacks. With grep I filter the rows, which now contain one or more * and count them. Then I list those lines, which contain more than one *. I used sed/grep/wc just for rapid prototyping.

Comment: An aequivalent solution in Java would involve multiple `line.replaceAll (pattern, replacement);` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like your approach.  Its too complicated.  I would create a Card class (with a constructor that takes a String, the ones found in the file) that has a value field.  That way you could just get each 2-card hand and check if the values equals 21.

Comment: Yeah It is more object oriented, I am trying this exercise to reinforce my skills in java, but I know It the first that comes to my mind